# How to convert xt::sum expression result to an integer

Tags: c++, xtensor

I am just starting out with xtensor and I am already stuck in a basic problem.

I am using something like `xt::sum(xt::where(egoLaneLeftCount, 1, 0))` to sum a column and get a single integer value. I want to save this integer value into a variable but I get the following `compilation error`.

```
xt::xreducer<xt::xreducer_functors<std::plus<long long int>, xt::const_value<long long int>, std::plus<long long int> >, xt::xfunction<xt::detail::conditional_ternary, const xt::xarray_container<xt::uvector<bool, std::allocator<bool> >, (xt::layout_type)1, xt::svector<long unsigned int, 4, std::allocator<long unsigned int>, true>, xt::xtensor_expression_tag>&, xt::xscalar<int>, xt::xscalar<int> >, xt::svector<long unsigned int, 4, std::allocator<long unsigned int>, true>, xt::reducer_options<long long int, std::tuple<xt::evaluation_strategy::lazy_type> > >
```

Any body has any idea how can I cast the result of this data type to an `int` ?

Answer (score 2):

The xt::sum will return a "xtensor type" ([xexpression](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/expression.html)). It states that "Values are only computed upon access or when the expression is assigned to a container". Hence, to get the value you want try the following:

```cpp
xt::xtensor<double, 1> egoLaneLeftCount = { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 };
int x = xt::sum(xt::where(egoLaneLeftCount, 1, 0))[0];
```